# Define a Generic List property in a static class

Tags: c#, list, generics

I need to use a static class to hold some simple values during runtime:

```
public static class Globals
{
    public static string UserName
    { get; set; }

     ...more properties
}
```

I now have need to store a List of objects - typed according to classes I have defined. This List will be re-used for different Object types, and so I thought to define it as Generic.
This is where I am stuck: how do I define a property inside a static class that will be containing different types of Lists at different times in the applications execution?

Needs to be something like :

```
    public List<T> Results {get; set;}
```

Comment: Since your class is named Globals, it seems like you're heading down a wrong path here. What do you need the list to contain, and why should it be generic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to define your class as a [Generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class.

```
public static class Globals<T>
{
    public static string UserName
    { get; set; }
    public static List<T> Results { get; set; }

}
```

later you can use it like:

```
Globals<string>.Results = new List<string>();
```

*Also your property `Results` needs to be private. You may consider exposing your methods to interact with the list, instead of exposing the list through a property.*

See: [C#/.NET Fundamentals: Returning an Immutable Collection](http://web.archive.org/web/20101109203615/http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/11/04/c.net-fundamentals-returning-an-immutable-collection.aspx)

Comment: Awesome stuff! Thanks Habib!